# Outlook 2010 Macro display mail when reminders fire

Tags: vba, email, outlook, outlook-2010

i have several reminders set up and wanted difference emails to be shown and ready to be sent when the reminders fire.  i know how to do one reminder but several has been giving me endless problems.

please see code that i currently have below, i have tries the if else code as well but not getting working at all.  currently this one is just not picking up the reminder information.  it gives me errors where the code refers to the reminder information.

```
'Private Sub Application_Reminder(ByVal Item As Object)

Dim objMsg As MailItem

Set objMsg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
If Item.MessageClass <> "IPM.Appointment" Then Exit Sub

If Item.Categories = "Branch Orders" Then Call BranchOrders
If Item.Categories = "Cust 1st Daily" Then Call CustDaily
If Item.Categories = "COH" Then Call COH
If Item.Categories = "Cust 1st Weekly" Then Call CustWeekly
If Item.Categories = "ATM Status And Avail" Then Call ATMSA

End Sub

Sub BranchOrders()
Dim objMsg As MailItem

Set objMsg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)

objMsg.To = Item.Location
objMsg.CC = ("bunch@hi.com")
objMsg.Subject = Item.Subject
objMsg.Body = Item.Body
objMsg.Display
Set objMsg = Nothing


End Sub


Sub CustDaily()
Dim objMsg As MailItem

Set objMsg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)

objMsg.To = Item.Location
objMsg.CC = ("afew@mails.com")
objMsg.Subject = Item.Subject
objMsg.Body = Item.Body
objMsg.Display
Set objMsg = Nothing


End Sub



Sub COH()
Dim objMsg As MailItem

Set objMsg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)

objMsg.To = Item.Location
objMsg.CC = ("just@one.com")
objMsg.Subject = Item.Subject
objMsg.Body = Item.Body
objMsg.Display
Set objMsg = Nothing


End Sub


Sub CustWeekly()
Dim objMsg As MailItem

Set objMsg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)

objMsg.To = Item.Location
objMsg.Subject = Item.Subject
objMsg.Body = Item.Body
objMsg.Display
Set objMsg = Nothing


End Sub


Sub ATMSA()
Dim objMsg As MailItem

Set objMsg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)

objMsg.To = Item.Location
objMsg.Subject = Item.Subject
objMsg.Body = Item.Body
objMsg.Display
Set objMsg = Nothing

End If

End Sub'
```

thank you

Comment: What line does the error occur on, and what is the message/number?

Comment: error is object does not exist,  getting it on all the lines that refer to the reminder information.  examples below          objMsg.To = Item.Location
objMsg.Subject = Item.Subject
objMsg.Body = Item.Body

Comment: runtime error 424 - object required

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to handle the [BeforeReminderShow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff867326(v=office.15).aspx) event of the Reminders class (see Application.Reminders) and don't display any mail item later.

Comment: have tried adding the beforeremindershow event, but im doing something wrong.  not understanding how that works.  also where do i need to look for application.reminders.  sorry this is my first time working with outlook macros and reminders.

Comment: I'd suggest astrting from the [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736(v=office.14).aspx) article. In the event handler you may set a global variable which can tell whether a reminder is displayed at the moment or not.

Comment: ive looked through the pages, but not finding anything that will help with this one.  there is very limited info about macros on reminders.

Comment: What exactly you are looking for? Is the event fired?

Comment: the reminder does go off and the macro does fire, but it gives an error when it fires as stated on the above comments.